# How to create feature module using angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

I am using angular-cli to create a feature module. Earlier this module was sitting as just another module in my main angular application (also created using angular-cli). Now I want to move it to a separate module that it can be published separately and others can use it as 3rd party library.

I was able to publish it but when I am trying to use it my main angular application, import fails. I can see that my feature module exists in the node_modules folder but the directory structure is very different from all the 3rd party angular library I am using (bootstrap , angular-split etc).

It looks like the directory structure for my feature module is incorrect. How to create a feature module using angular-cli and how the directory structure should look like?

[image]

Comment: I see two questions contained: 1) How to generate a feature module with the CLI 2) How to publish that feature module via NPM and then use it from there. I think the question is too broad. Can you provide more details? Probably you solved it by now already.